# Python // Reading from lines following a given input

Tags: linux, python

I am trying to get Python to find text in a file that appears *after* a query I give it. For instance, the familiar "sources.list". I want to get everything in the same line after every instance of the text "deb". Take my Raspberry Pi's "sources.list":

```
deb [link]

# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src [link] jessie main contrib non-free rpi

deb [link] jessie main

deb [link] oldstable main
```

Now I want to retrieve everything that appears after each instance of "deb" and stick it into a separate file. Is that possible in Python?

Comment: Are you opposed to using `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, or `perl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Gratz, you are the reason I made this account lol,

secondly, assuming you are like me and you frontline the python releases, you are using python 3(.6),

Getting specific with Strings is something handled extremely well in Python,

I'ma make this fast, and let you figure out the rest (For you, not just for me.)

Python's dirty syntax allows things to be fairly generic while also being incredibly specific. There are a couple of ways you could get this done but for your particular example I would just use the space method, which is using spaces to isolate results despite their changing/varying lengths and character-makeups.

```
StringYouWantToParse = "deb [link] jessie deb [link] oldstable"
```

Notice the spaces in the string. Based on what you posted, that is more or less an accurate example of the kind of string you would end up with, after extracting them all from the list.

```
 _________________________________________
|   Dr.w0bb13z Rx# 30041995000CID-3340R1  |
|_________________________________________|
| IsolatedResults = ["",""]               |  
|                                         |
| cntr   =     0                          |
| space_cntr = 0                          |
|                                         |
| for char in StringYouWantToParse:       |
|    |                                    |
|    |if char is ' ':                     |
|       |space_cntr += 1                  |
|       |                                 |
|       |if (space_cntr % 3) is 0:        |
|          cntr += 1                      |
| else:                                   |
|      IsolatedResults[cntr] += char      |
l_________________________________________l
```

Take 3 of those every day moo
(P.S: That code is hand script. I did not test this in any way. But due to its simplistic nature I'm pretty sure it would work, but again, don't let me have all the fun, your ability to code is directly correlated with your true desire to learn.)

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Oh. I came here from Google. 
YAH! RIDE MONTAHUE! (m0o)